# How to convert boolean value to string

Tags: c#

I just want to get a checkbox checked and unchecked value as `"-1"` and `"0"`.
I am trying this way :

```
Conversions.ToString((-((CheckBox1.Checked) ? 1 : 0)) ? 1 : 0)
```

but get following error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'

How can i do it using similar expression..?

Comment: Why do you have *two* conditional operators? Why are you using `Conversions.ToString` (whatever that is) at all? Why not just `CheckBox1.Checked ? "-1" : "0"`?

Comment: As a thumb rule, try to keep your code simple and readable. The first conditional does not return a `boolean` expression but an `int`, so the second conditional raises an error. In this case, you could use only one conditional, as @JonSkeet mentions (or fix your first conditional, but makes no sense having two).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string checkedValue = CheckBox1.Checked ? "-1" : "0";
```

Answer (score 2):

The property `CheckBox1.Checked` will give you a boolean value, so you can apply the ternary operator to evaluate them. There is no need for convert.ToString() method here since you can assign true case(`"-1"`) and false case (`"0"`) to a string variable as like the following:

```
string checkedState = CheckBox1.Checked ? "-1" : "0";
```

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ROncZ8) you can find an example to assign some string value based on some condition

Comment: Ehmm, this seems to be the same answer as @Dmitry's answer.

Comment: @Stefan: When I hit post I got `StackOverflow went offline for update message` few minutes later `F5` key press for refreshing the browser posted the same. that makes my post as duplicate of the other. Anyway sorry for the repeated answer